# How to improve inference of a function

Tags: julia, type-inference, cdf

I'm using Julia 0.4.7 since I have some old code and in my application it's faster than 0.5.1.

I'm trying to compute the empirical CDF of a long vector of `Int`s. For that, I'm using `searchsortedlast(data, x)/n`, where `data` is a sorted `Vector{Int}`, `x` is an `Int` and `n=length(data)`.

I have to compute the CDF of many vectors, and I'm finding that very slow. I think that the slowdown is because inference is failing somewhere in `searchsortedlast` (there is an `Any` in the body):

```
@code_warntype searchsortedlast(data, 2000)

Variables:
  v::Array{Int64,1}
  x::Int64

Body:
  begin $(Expr(:line, 184, symbol("sort.jl"), symbol("")))
      return (Base.Sort.searchsortedlast)(v::Array{Int64,1},x::Int64,(Base.Sort.ord)(Base.Sort.isless,Base.Sort.identity,false,Base.Sort.Forward)::Any)::Int64
  end::Int64
```

I have looked at the [source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/ae26b25d43317d7dd3ca05f60b70677aab9c0e08/base/sort.jl#L184) of `searchsortedlast` but I can't figure out how to improve inference there (there are many method definitions that confuse me, but is not that I'm an expert Julia programmer anyways). Maybe I can annotate something somewhere, but don't know where. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

There is really nothing you can do, short of upgrading to 0.5, where the problem is fixed. 0.4 simply does not have the ability to dispatch on function types like 0.5, which is why the `ord` call is type unstable.

Note that this particular type instability is harmless — since the function's return type is still stable, the only added cost is a single dynamic dispatch to `searchsortedlast` on every invocation, which is a small cost compared to the cost of searching a large array.

Comment: But I find that 0.5 is slower anyways.

Comment: Then open a new question with "why is XYZ slower on JuliaLang v0.5 than v0.4.7?" with an example people can run.